Convert key value object to array of objects
I have object key value in below format.
{
    "Code1": {
        "char10": "ch1",
        "number1": "1",
        "text1": "txt1"
    },
    "Code2": {
        "char2": "ch2",
        "num2": "2"
    },
    "Code3": {
        "text": "txt4"
    }
}

Would like to convert to this format :
{
  "Code1": [
    {
      "char10": "ch1",
      "number1": "1",
      "text1": "txt1"
    }
  ],
  "Code2": [
    {
      "char2": "ch2",
      "num2": "2"
    }
  ],
  "Code3": [
    {
      "text": "txt4"
    }
  ]
}

Managed to achieve to get somewhat similar response but not exact output which I am looking for.
Tried the below snippet but it returns diff format than expected.
Object.entries(payload).map((e) => ( { [e[0]]: e[1] } ))

Response with above snippet :
[
    {
        "Code1": {
            "char10": "ch1",
            "number1": "1",
            "text1": "txt1"
        }
    },
    {
        "Code2": {
            "char2": "ch2",
            "num2": "2"
        }
    },
    {
        "Code3": {
            "text": "txt4"
        }
    }
]


Array.map() will always return an array

I have updated the sample correctly. I am getting key value in object format and have to convert it to desired format for sending it as payload in one of the REST api.

You have an answer. Use fromEntries to take the mapped output of entries and create an object from it. You were off with your map call, that's all.

for (let key in payload) payload[key] = [payload[key]]; is a basic way. Or assign the props to a new object.

You could get all entries and map with wrapped values for a new object.


const
    data = { Code1: { char10: "ch1", number1: "1", text1: "txt1" }, Code2: { char2: "ch2", num2: "2" }, Code3: { text: "txt4" } },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(data)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, [v]])
    );

console.log(result);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }




You can solve this problem by using Object.entries() with reduce() to transform each entry into an array containing an object.
Here's how you can do it :
const payload = {
    "Code1": {
        "char10": "ch1",
        "number1": "1",
        "text1": "txt1"
    },
    "Code2": {
        "char2": "ch2",
        "num2": "2"
    },
    "Code3": {
        "text": "txt4"
    }
};

const transformed = Object.entries(payload).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    acc[key] = [value];
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(transformed);


You will need to reduce the objects's entries and for each key value pair, assign the key to the result object and supply it with the value wrapped inside of an array.
I wrote a reusable function below, that takes an optional valueMapper which can transform the value upon assignment to the resulting object.


const data = {
  Code1: { char10: 'ch1', number1: '1', text1: 'txt1' },
  Code2: { char2:  'ch2', num2: '2' },
  Code3: { text:   'txt4' }
}

const result = reduceEntries(data, (v) => [v]); // Wrap the value in an array

console.log(result);

function reduceEntries(obj, valueMapper) {
  return Object.entries(data).reduce((result, [key, value]) =>
    Object.assign(result, {
      [key]: valueMapper ? valueMapper(value, key) : value
    }) ,{});
}
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }



Of course, it can also be written using Array.prototype.map and Object.fromEntries; instead of Array.prototype.reduce and Object.assign. Either solution will work.
function reduceEntries(obj, valueMapper) {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) =>
    [key, valueMapper ? valueMapper(value, key) : value]));
}

